# Why parent class method is getting called and not child class in this case?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a parent class A, and its child B. Both are having `doSomething` method with diff type of parameters.

Class A

```
package Inheritance;

public class A {

    public void doSomething(Object str){
        System.out.println("Base impl:"+str);
    }
}
```

Class B

```
package Inheritance;

public class B extends A{

    public void doSomething(String str){
        System.out.println("Child impl:"+str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new B();
        a.doSomething("override");

    }
}
```

When I run this, I'm getting "Base impl:override" as the output!

`a` is pointing to an object of `B`, and the he passed argument is `String`, So shouldn't it call `B`'s `doSomething(String str)` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using a reference of type A, you see only the methods defined for class A. Since `doSomething` in B doesn't override `doSomething` in A (since it has a different signature), it is not called.

If you were to use a reference of type B, both methods would be available, and `doSomething` of B would be chosen, since it has a more specific argument (String vs Object).

Comment: you mean to say when I do: 'A a = new B();'
'a.doSomething("override");' First compiler will check A class for doSomething(String) and it is not present! Then finds that A has doSomething(Object), since doSomething(Object) is not overriddden in B class, parent's doSomething(Object) is called. Am I right?

Comment: @PraveeshP yes. `doSomething(Object)` is the only method in A that matches the call `a.doSomething("override")`

Comment: That means whenever I do 'ParentClass obj = new ChildClass();' and use obj to call any method, Compiler will first check for that method in ParentClass as obj is of type Parent. If found, it will check whether ChildClass has overridden the same. Is that the flow?

Comment: @PraveeshP almost. Compiler would find a method in ParentClass that best fits the arguments of the method call. If it doesn't find any, the code wouldn't compile. Only at runtime the JVM will check the actual type of the `obj` instance, and based on that call the ChildClass method if it overrides the ParentClass method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not considered a case of method overriding because the signatures are not exactly the same.  Change the String argument to Object in B.

Answer (score 0):

In class A, you have declared a method `doSomething(Object obj)`. However, in class B, you have declared the method `doSomething(String str)`, which has a different parameter type than the one in class A. This means that class B's `doSomething` doesn't override class A's `doSomething`.

To get the desired output, do the following (I omitted the main methods to get a more generic code sample):

```
public class A {
    public void doSomething(Object str){
        System.out.println("Base impl:"+str);
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    // Helpful annotation: It tells you
    // if you aren't overriding any known method
    @Override
    public void doSomething(Object str) {
        System.out.println("Child impl:"+str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Eran said

**When you are using a reference of type A, you see only the methods defined for class A. Since doSomething in B doesn't override doSomething in A (since it has a different signature), it is not called.**

if you wanna call the method defined in B you need to cast it as following

```
((B)a).doSomething("override");
```

or you have to used the instance of B implicitly